# Bash script на ввод пароля

Tags: bash

Подскажите пожалуйста. есть скрипт для автодеплоя на сервер. там есть команда типа

```
ssh $SSH_HOST
```

далее нужно ввести пароль и дальше продолжается чтение скрипта и выполнение команд.

как сдать чтобы пароль был задан в скрипте и автоматически подставлялся? Спасибо!

Comment: сделать то можно, но не проще public key положить ?

Comment: @ennet, смотрите в сторону `expect`. Либо поищите в сети утилитку sshpass (или напишите ее аналог под себя).

В любом случае с ssh надо общаться через псевдотерминал (другие интерфейсы он не понимает).

Answer (score 1):

фу таким быть :)

```
ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa
cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-copy-id <user>@<hostname>
ssh <user>@<hostname>
```

upd: да, `cp` необязательно, а даже и не нужно на source хосте :) простите :)

Comment: Только вот после этого всегда будет можно с этой машины на hostname без пароля ходить (конечно на user и с того же местного аккунта).

Это не всегда хорошо.

Comment: например? ОБЫЧНО для деплоя делается пользователь отдельный, который имеет только определенные права, на source хосте тоже отдельный пользователь, вы ему можете не задавать пароль, тогда под него нельзя будет залогиниться, т.е. не рут пользователь не сможет под ним зайти (su <user> не прокатит уже)... совершенно секурно и безопасно. или хотите сказать, что вводить пароль в шелле это лучше? ;)

Comment: @thunder, у Вас все как в теории (как должно быть). 

--

А на практике обычно все делают рутом и из под рута. На куче удаленных машин разом (даже если прямого рутового захода по сети на них нет). А потом менять пароли или вытирать что-нибудь забывают.... 

Причем машина с которой ставят доступна с рутовым заходом многим физически разным сотрудникам. 

А открытый рутовый пароль в скрипте -- это тоже очень плохо.

Comment: @avp ну у меня так работает на практике, поэтому и делюсь как НАДО делать :) настаивать не буду, но пробую направить в правильное русло.     
на моих внешних серверах вообще пароль рута выпилен сразу после добавления моего рабочего юзера, вход под рутом по ссх так же выпилен, включена авторизация только по ключу, фаерволлом закрыто все, что не должно наружу смотреть... на ssh натравлен fail2ban с одной попыткой входа и баном по IP на сутки... без этого постоянно ломились брутфорсеры, сейчас почти нету... очень редко кто ходит...

Comment: кстати я уж молчу, что пароль 99% будет отображен в логах системы :) а еще и логах bash history...

Comment: можно, если уж паранойя одолела, генерить в отдельный файл и использовать ключик -i, насчет fail2ban :) проще запретить вообще по паролю логиниться.

Comment: можно, но как выяснилось об этом ключике мало кто знает)
запрещено, но это не мешает брутерам пробовать, а нафига мне логи плодить) так забанил и они перестают ломиться... главное способ работает...

Answer (score 0):

`sshpass` копай [вот тут](https://serverfault.com/a/512220)

Ну или `expect` (зверский костыль).

Но правильней (как мне кажется) все-таки через ключик.

Answer (score -1):

Можно запустить скрипт с параметром (паролем) вот так - sh run.sh pass

А внутри достать его -

```
PASS=$1
echo PASS
```

$1 это первый входящий аргумент для скрипта, так же можно передавать несколько аргументов используя $1 $2 $3 ...

Comment: ssh этот пароль не передастся, либо ключем - что правильно, либо если уж совсем не возможно, то expect, и ещё какой-то способ был(может putty использовать под linux ?), но я не помню.

Comment: ойли   
`ssh user:password@hostname` ?

а не, так тоже не прокатит :)

Comment: нужно ставить стороннюю утилиту `sshpass`, тогда можно будет:
`sshpass -p <password> ssh user@hostname`

Comment: ну и насчет expect читать и смотреть примеры [тут][1]

[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect